# How to add image upload with text in LangServe api

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

I am creating a LLM Chat API using LangServe. What I want is to offer user functionality to either upload image or use text to chat. So how to create a chatbot in LangServe that uses image and text input and can also have a option to add image in LangServe Playground.

I was able to create a simple chatbot with text, but not able to do with image. I want to create a agent, so whenever the input contains image I will parse it with easyocr and then pass to LLM and give user answer. Any Help would highly appreciated.